# Getting file size using readdir

Tags: c, linux

I am calling `readdir()` to get info from a directory for file names. I also want to print the file sizes using `readdir()` only if possible as the structure of `dirent` is

```
struct dirent {
               ino_t          d_ino;       /* inode number */
               off_t          d_off;       /* offset to the next dirent */
               unsigned short d_reclen;    /* length of this record */
               unsigned char  d_type;      /* type of file; not supported
                                              by all file system types */
               char           d_name[256]; /* filename */
           };
```

I am using `d_reclen` as the file size but somehow my program prints wrong values. But my questions are :

1. Is it right to use `d_reclen` as the file size? Because my doubt is that it is unsigned short and how can it return correct size for large files.
2. What is actually length of record? Is this size in bytes? How can I calculate correct size?

**OUTPUT**

```
Actual Size :1bytes File size :20
Actual Size :4bytes File size :20
Actual Size :8bytes File size :20
Actual Size :256bytes File size :20
Actual Size :0bytes File size :20
Actual Size :255bytes File size :20
Actual Size :1023bytes File size :24
```

**EDIT 1**
I am using `printf("File size :%hu\n",pent->d_reclen);` to print file size but it is not giving the correct answer.

**EDIT 2**
I want to avoid the usage of `stat()` for some performance reasons.

Comment: From [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) .. `The only fields in the dirent structure that are mandated by POSIX.1 are: d_name[], of unspecified size, with at most NAME_MAX characters preceding the terminating null byte ('\0'); and (as an XSI extension) d_ino.  The other fields are unstandardized, and not present on all systems.`

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Portability is not an issue.

Comment: 1) Rather than report "not giving the correct answer", reporting the output and expected output is more useful 2) The value of `d_reclen` is the record length of this entry, not file size. 3) IMO, `stat()`.

Comment: @chux : Please see the edit. And how record length differnt from size? I mean what's the record contains. I though record is the file data so record length is the file size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the file size, as opposed to the size (length) of the file name (which is what is recorded in `d_reclen`), you need either the `stat()` or `statat()` (or `lstat()`) system call.  You can't get the file size directly from the information in `struct dirent`.

Answer (score 3):

The [`readdir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) manual says:

> ```
> unsigned short d_reclen;    /* length of this record */
> ```

"This record" is "this `struct dirent` instance", not "this file".

In your case (`d_reclne` 20 or 24) you should not access the whole dirent memory, because readdir allocated only enough memory to fill in `d_ino`, `d_off`, `d_reclen`, `d_type` and the relevant parts of `d_name`. `readdir` did not allocate the complete 256 bytes for `d_name`.